# Mirrors failing for RHEL 7 yum install

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum

I have a RHEL 7 that has connectivity to the internet and no proxy in between.
I can ping 8.8.8.8
I am trying to install grafana (an application for dashboards) based on official docs: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/rpm/

I am unable to do a yum install for this:

```
 sudo yum install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/grafana-releases/release/grafana-4.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cannot open: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/grafana-releases/release/grafana-4.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
```

If I follow these instructions:

```
 wget https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/grafana-releases/release/grafana-4.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo yum install initscripts fontconfig
$ sudo rpm -Uvh grafana-4.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I can download the rpm, but I once again get stuck at line #2 - yum install
Am I missing something? I've previously installed other packages using yum on the same machine and it worked fine.

Comment: It is possible that yum is using ipv6 to try to connect to the internet, but you have configuration issues with said ipv6. Try `ping6 google.com` and add the results to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install grafana package on my Lab and it is installed successfully by using

> yum install
>   https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/grafana-releases/release/grafana-4.3.1-1.x86_64.rpm

So maybe the problem with your internet speed ?? tell me what is your connection speed and is it stable connection ??